# Correct syntax to GLOB whitespace in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to build a glob pattern which include spaces. I've tried `\\` (escape the escape since it is java plus space) , `[\\ ]` and `[[:space:]]`. I've no idea how to implement this. It seems simple and stupid, but I've not found any documentation on this (sqlite glob implementation).

I can't use LIKE, because rest of my expression uses charranges (`[a-d]`, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GLOB documentation is hidden in the source code:

```
Globbing rules:

     '*'       Matches any sequence of zero or more characters.

     '?'       Matches exactly one character.

    [...]      Matches one character from the enclosed list of
               characters.

    [^...]     Matches one character not in the enclosed list.

With the [...] and [^...] matching, a ']' character can be included
in the list by making it the first character after '[' or '^'.  A
range of characters can be specified using '-'.  Example:
"[a-z]" matches any single lower-case letter.  To match a '-', make
it the last character in the list.

Hints: to match '*' or '?', put them in "[]".  Like this:

        abc[*]xyz        Matches "abc*xyz" only
```

---

A space can be matched with just a space in the pattern:

```
> SELECT ' ' GLOB ' ';
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used `[ ]` syntax

`*[ ]*` to match string with spaces